# R: recode previous/following n observations

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of 0/1 dummy variables. Each dummy variable only takes the value 1 once. For each column, I would want to replace n preceding/following observations counting from the observation with the value 1 to a particular value (say 1).

So for single vector, with n=1:

```
c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

I would want to get

```
c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

What would be a good general approach with n columns and allowing for a different number of preceding/following observations to replace (e.g n-1 before & n after)?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Something like `as.numeric(filter(x, rep(1,3), circular = TRUE))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
f <- function(x, pre, post) {
  idx <- which.max(x)
  x[max(1, (idx-pre)):min(length(x), (idx+post))] <- 1
  x
}
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), y = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Application:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, f, pre=2, post=1)
#df
#  x y
#1 1 1
#2 1 1
#3 1 1
#4 1 0
#5 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x<-c(0,0,1,0,0)
ind<-which(x==1)
x[(ind-1):(ind+x)]<-1
```

Comment: Very simple and fast solution, however, you are missing one check, for example: run your code on the vector `x <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)`, you need to check that `ind` is above 0 and below `length(x)`

Comment: Which you can do with this line: `x[(max(0, ind-1)):min((ind+x), length(x))]<-1`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is the following:

```
vec <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)

sapply(1:length(vec), function(i) {
  minval <- max(0, i - 1)
  maxval <- min(i + 1, length(vec))
  return(sum(vec[minval:maxval]))
})
# [1] 0 1 1 1 0
```

Or to put it in a function (same code but a bit more compact)

```
f <- function(vec){
  sapply(1:length(vec), function(i)
                sum(vec[max(0, i-1):min(i+1, length(vec))]))
}

f(vec)
# [1] 0 1 1 1 0
```

## Speedtest

To compare the two different solutions, I quickly ran a benchmark using `microbenchmark`, and the winner is: Clearly @Shenglin's code.... Always nice to see simple solutions (as well as to see how complicated some (my) solutions can be).

```
fDavid <- function(vec){
  sapply(1:length(vec), function(i)
    sum(vec[max(0, i-1):min(i+1, length(vec))]))
}
fHeroka <- function(vec){
  res <- vec
  test <- which(vec==1)

  #create indices to be replaced

  n=1 #variable n
  replace_indices <- c(test+(1:n),test-(1:n))
  #filter out negatives (may happen with larger n)
  replace_indices <- replace_indices[replace_indices>0]
  #replace items in 'res' that need to be replaced with 1

  res[replace_indices] <- 1
}
fShenglin <- function(vec){

  ind<-which(vec==1)
  vec[(ind-1):(ind+x)]<-1
}

vect <- sample(0:1, size = 1000, replace = T)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fHeroka(vect), fDavid(vect), fShenglin)
# # Unit: nanoseconds
# expr     min      lq       mean  median        uq     max
# fHeroka(vect)   38929   42999   54422.57   49546   61755.5  145451
# fDavid(vect) 2463805 2577935 2875024.99 2696844 2849548.5 5994596
# fShenglin       0       0     138.63       1     355.0    1063
# neval cld
# 100  a 
# 100   b
# 100  a 
# Warning message:
#   In microbenchmark(fHeroka(vect), fDavid(vect), fShenglin) :
#   Could not measure a positive execution time for 30 evaluations.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a start:

```
myv <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)

#make a copy
res <- myv

#check where the ones are
test <- which(myv==1)

#create indices to be replaced

n=1 #variable n
replace_indices <- c(test+(1:n),test-(1:n))
#filter out negatives (may happen with larger n)
replace_indices <- replace_indices[replace_indices>0]
#replace items in 'res' that need to be replaced with 1

res[replace_indices] <- 1
res

    > res
    [1] 0 1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```
dat<-data.frame(x=c(0,0,1,0,0,0),y=c(0,0,0,1,0,0),z=c(0,1,0,0,0,0))
which_to_change<-data.frame(prev=c(2,2,1),foll=c(1,1,3))
for(i in 1:nrow(which_to_change)){
  dat[(which(dat[,i]==1)-which_to_change[i,1]):(which(dat[,i]==1)+which_to_change[i,2]),i]<-1
}
```